# laravel eloquent with return only same column values

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is a little complex for me,so I decided to get some help.

Taxonomy has :

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Product::class,
            'term_relationships',
            'term_taxonomy_id',
            'object_id'
        );
    }
```

And Product has :

```
public function taxonomies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Taxonomy::class,
            'term_relationships',
            'object_id',
            'term_taxonomy_id'
        );
    }
```

This will select all products with all its taxonomies where taxonomy starts with pa_.

```
\Corcel\WooCommerce\Model\ProductCategory::find(401)->products()->with(['taxonomies'=> function ($query) {
        $query->where('taxonomy', 'like', "pa_%");
    }])->get(['ID'])->makeHidden(['pivot']);
```

All I want is to select only taxonomies which all have the same taxonomy column value.
like they all have : `taxonomy -> pa_shirt_size and taxonomy -> pa_shirt_color`

Here's the sql output of eloquent :

```
select * from `wp_posts` inner join `wp_term_relationships` on `wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_term_relationships`.`object_id`
where `post_type` = 'product' and `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id` = 401 and exists (select * from
    `wp_term_taxonomy` inner join `wp_term_relationships` on `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id` =
                                                             `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id` where `wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_term_relationships`.`object_id` and `taxonomy`
    like 'pa_%')
```

So I think using something like :

```
group by `taxonomy` having count(*) = count(wp.posts.ID)
```

I can get the number of posts and if that is equal to taxonomy count it means we're good.
But how to access wp.posts.ID from the subquery in with function I couldn't find a way yet.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get the products' count, then get all the taxonomies that have all the products count:

```
 $Products_count = Product::count();
  $sharedTaxomies  = Taxonomy::has('products', '=', $Products_count)->get();
```

**note**: I suppoe the relation in Taxonomy called `products` not `posts`.

Comment: Your idea is fantastic but I don't want to really see what taxonomy all the products have It's a little more complex I need to select the products first then in the selected products I need to do this so this solution doesn't work directly but maybe if we could change it a bit it could cover that.

Answer (score 0):

first: i think you mean products() instead posts() ?

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Product::class,
            'term_relationships',
            'term_taxonomy_id',
            'object_id'
        );
    }
```

Secound: if you have access to products like:

```
$products = Product::all();
```

you can after iterate the $products and you have access to the taxonomies like:

```
print_r( $products[0]->taxonomies );
```

Comment: Yeah the first part is products not posts just a typo.and your solution is great but not for when we having thousands of products.

Comment: Maybe I haven't quite understood the question yet. 

You don't have to ask for all products:
$products = Product::where('brand', 'BRANDNAME')->get();
And now you can query the taxonomies of every single product. 

Or do you want to filter the products by their taxonomies? Then build your raw query .

$products = Product::with(['taxonomies' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('taxonomy_name', 'like', '%my_taxo%');
}])->get();

Comment: A little bit of both actually and still more I didn't explain well so I updated the question now.Please check it once again.